# passing arguments to management.call_command on a django view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a command i run from the command line that takes two arguments,-tzusb and -e.
I have converted this so that it is called on a django view.
I have a little glitch though,
How do i pass this arguments to the management.call_command function I have in my views?
here is my view for that

```
def tzusbcsv(request):
    management.call_command('artifact_db_loader','artefacts')
    return render_to_response('html/upload.html')
```

Answer (score 19):

In your command you should find the option definitions which should look like the following:

```
make_option('-tzsub', dest='tzsub', action='store_true', help='Help description...')
make_option('-e', dest='e', action='store_true', help='Help description...')
```

Have a look on them and take into account "dest" argument for each one. Assuming you defined dest='tzsub' for -tzsub and dest='e' for -e (like in the example above), you should call the command in this way:

```
management.call_command('artifact_db_loader','artefacts', tzsub=True, e=True)
```

This is the same of calling the command from your console like this:

```
python manage.py artifact_db_loader artefacts -tzsub -e
```

Of course if the parameters need any arguments (so you have action='store' in the option definition) simply replace the boolean argument with the value you need. For instance:

```
management.call_command('artifact_db_loader','artefacts', tzsub='wow!', e=7)
```

This is the same of calling the command in this way:

```
python manage.py artifact_db_loader artefacts -tzsub "wow!" -e 7
```

Comment: HI Marco,this looks exactly like what i wanted,because i pass arguments from the command the same same way you have here python manage.py artifact_db_loader artefacts -tzsub "wow!" -e 7 so where should i find the make_option definition?

Comment: Hi Joshua, you can get all commands path calling this function: management.get_commands(). In your case you could try: management.get_commands()['artifact_db_loader']. You can try it directly from the shell (python manage.py shell) after the module import (from django.core import management).

Comment: Inside that path there should be this module: management.commands.artifact_db_loader.py

Comment: Hi,Marco, i tried the procedure you highlighted here make_option('-tzsub', dest='tzsub', action='store_true', help='Help description...')
make_option('-e', dest='e', action='store_true', help='Help description...') but i get an error like "invalid long option string '-tzsub': must start with --, followed by non-dash" what might be wrong with this?

Comment: Hi,am able to make artififact_db_loader.py above a management command,but am not able to pass arguments -tzusb and -e that i was passing initially from command line as artifact_db_loader.py -tzusb "c:\desktop.csvfile.csv" -e 44.. anyone with a clue on how to make this possible so that i can be able to pass this arguments from my view when i call this command?

Comment: Also, if your argument is something like "--natural-foreign", you should use "natural_foreign=True"